# libspotify and const char * lifetimes / encoding

Tags: spotify

Are the various libspotify APIs that return const char* returning caller owned strings or callee owned strings?

The normal convention, as far as I know, is that const char* means the callee owns it and the caller can use it but not necessarily rely on its lifetime and is not expected to free it.

Is this the pattern Spotify follows?

Also I saw some mention in the api.h file that the strings are UTF8 encoded?  I assume this is true on all APIs not just the one or two that explicitly mention it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `const char *` returns are owned by libSpotify unless stated otherwise. You don't need to free() them, and if you want them to stick around you should copy them - for example, a playlist name's `const char *` will be freed by libSpotify when the playlist's name changes. The "Add your own locks" section of the [libSpotify FAQ](http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/faq/) discusses this a little bit.

2) All strings are UTF-8.